# 2 iad banners error

Tags: ios

If only one iAd banner, everything is Ok. It can fetch the ad banner.
But if I put iAd banner view in two views/viewcontrollers, it will display

```
[AppDeveloper]: ADBannerView: Unhandled error 
(no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error     
Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 

Loading throttled" UserInfo=0xab6ec20 {ADInternalErrorCode=2,    
ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Loading throttled}
```

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your problem is that you aren't setting a `delegate` for each iAd banner.

**Second**, there is a **serious implementation problem** in your app. You should never make multiple iAd banners just to show on two different screens. You need to use a shared banner managed by a central object, like your delegate. Google `shared iAd banner` for help.